# Import excel is not working when I try to skip a data

Tags: laravel, import, laravel-8, laravel-9, import-from-excel

I'm having a problem (without errors) when I try to import data, skipping the email if already present, from an external file; the data is not imported.

This is my code.

**ImportClass**

```
namespace App\Imports;

use App\Models\Client;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Row;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\OnEachRow;

class ClientsImport implements OnEachRow
{
    public function onRow(Row $row)
    {
        $row = $row->toArray();

        $contact = Client::firstOrCreate(
            ['email' => $row[3]],
            [
                'name'     => $row[1],
                'surname'    => $row[2],
                'email'    => $row[3],
                'city' => $row[4],
            ]

        );

        if (! $contact->wasRecentlyCreated) {
            $contact->update([
                'name'     => $row[1],
                'surname'    => $row[2],
                'city' => $row[4],
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
   public function importFile(Request $request) 
    {
        Excel::import(new ClientsImport, $request->file('file')->store('temp'));
        return back();
    }
```

Can anyone kindly help me?

Comment: Not sure to understand what you want exactly. Actually your import is not working at all as soon as you have an existing row? You may want to have a look at the skipOnError and skipOnFailure traits https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/validation.html

Comment: @FabriceLefloch What I want is that if the email is already there then skip it

Comment: What error are you having actually when you face an existing email? On your onRow method you just have to skip the line or add a return so you'll automatically skip to the next row of your file. Just in case if you need to create a model on each row (except for the emails already existing), you should rather use the toModel trait https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/model.html